# Vortice flow comparison

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vortex

Suppose the flow of a 1 square meter circle surface vortex. If instead of 1 vortex I stick say 100 smaller vortices in the same area.
Will the total flow of 100 parallel vortices be larger that the flow of one unique vortex?

Comment: What do you mean by "flow will be larger"? What are trying to compare?

Answer (score 0):

No. One big vortex will work better. The edge of one vortex will collide with another edge. This would happen in air, water and magnetic vortex fields as well.

The size of a vortex as far as water goes depends on the size of the drain hole and depth. You can have a drain with many holes in that meter but to many holes and the vortexes will never form.

Sometimes in tornadoes one tornadoes can start another in sister tornadoes, one clock wise and the other counterclockwise. They can get close without cancelling because the edges of the vortex are spinning in the same direction.

[image]

[image]